# Calculate in T-SQL FAST the high and low of the previous 1440 rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a row for every minute, with High and Low value. I want to calculate for the current row the highest value of the previous 1440 rows (=1day) and also the Low for this same period.

The datamodel is really simple.

```
TimeStamp           | High | Low
2020-01-01 01:01    |  10  |  8
2020-01-01 01:02    |  11  |  8
2020-01-01 01:03    |  11  |  6
...
```

and this for 10M rows

I have tried:

- self joining the MIN and MAX for the previous 1440 rows
- abusing the lag function to
- Creating a cursor to calculate the result row by row

All fail to run in under 2hrs...

So I hope to hit some spark of creativity with another approach.

My last resort would be Python where I can navigate this as a matrix.
However this should be really last resort.

Comment: `MAX/MIN() OVER...` not `LAG` surely? Also try this trick anywhere in your query to get batch mode `LEFT JOIN DummyColumnstoreTable ON 1 = 0`

Comment: create a sql fiddle with table structure, small subset of test data and a sql script that returns the expected results

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're looking for `over` w/ [rows/range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#rows-or-range)

```
select
    ...
    , [TimeStamp]
    , [PrecedingDayHigh] = MAX([High]) 
        over( order by [TimeStamp] desc ROWS BETWEEN 1339 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
    , [PrecedingDayLow] = MIN([Low])
        over( order by [TimeStamp] desc ROWS BETWEEN 1339 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW )
from
    ...
```

Comment: This is a correct answer. I forget to add this one also to the methods I tried. Still really slow unfortunately...

Comment: Do you have an index on the timestamp column?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . if you want the row with the highest `high`:

```
select top (1) t.*
from (select top (1440) t.*
      from t
      order by timestamp desc
     ) t
order by high desc;
```

You can do something similar for the highest or lowest low.

Comment: Looks like OP wants a rolling min/max for every row